# How to manipulate HTML within a jQuery variable?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to manipulate the HTML stored within a jQuery variable. I want to do this manipulation before I write the variable to the document.

So, I have a variable defined as:

```
var sighting = "<div><span class="feed_name"></span></div>";
```

And I want to put "hello world" in the `span` element.  This is the part that I can't get to work:

```
$(sighting).("span.feed_name").html(name);
```

Then I write the 'sighting' variable to the page:

```
$(#sightings).append(sighting);
```

Which puts the HTML in the sighting variable into the `<div id="sightings"></div>` element on the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: `$(sighting).("span.feed_name").html(name)` isn't even valid syntax. You'd want `$(sighting).find("span.feed_name").html(name)`.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer this method, you'll have more control over the elements because they remain as objects, and are thus easier to coerce into functions.

```
sighting = document.createElement('div');
```

Then you can manipulate as if it was already part of the DOM

```
$(sighting).addClass("feed_name").html(name);
$(sighting).appendTo("#sighting");
```

**EDIT**

Hmm... it seems I misread your question. I would still prefer to make the elements using the `createElement()` function.

```
sighting = document.createElement('div');
sighting_contents = document.createElement('span');

$(sighting_contents).addClass("feed_name").html(name);
$(sighting).append(sighting_contents);
$(sighting).appendTo("#sightings");
```

A little more verbose, but you can string the last three into one long line if you want... I think this is more readable and ultimately gives you more control, because technically you shouldn't be writing a bunch of HTML in your js, you can create the elements and append them, but as far as writing big blocks of markup I think creating the elements as objects like this gives you more flexibility.

You can also attach events to elements added like this in a more simple way:

```
$(sighting).bind("click", function(event) {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Hi Joseph,

Thanks for your reply!  This sounds like the approach I want, but when I write:

sighting1 = document.createElement("<div class='sighting1'></div>");

I get the js error:

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "String contains an invalid character"  code: "5" nsresult: "0x80530005 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR)"  location: "http://www.myurl.com Line: 47"]

Any ideas what this could be from?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Yes, that is the expected error. You don't need the html in the function just do:

`document.createElement('div');`

You can't put HTML into that function, just the tag of the element you want to create.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var sighting = "<div><span class=\"feed_name\"></span></div>",
    $elem = $(sighting).find("span.feed_name").text("hello world").parent();
$("#sightings").append($elem);
```

The `parent` call is needed to get back to the outer `div`.

Comment: LOL, you got it first and even with the same heading "Try this:" :D (my answer deleted)

Comment: Hi Gumbo,  Thanks for your help!  I ended up going with the other answer, but yours was helpful as well.  - Mark