# How do I change the value of an input box in a variable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a variable containing a form with an input box, and I'd like to change the value attribute of said input box using jquery. So far, I'm able to change the value, but it doesn't get changed in the outer html. This' what I've got so far:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    var form_content = "<form><input id=\"name\" value=\"Test value\"/></form>";
    var test = $('<div />').html(form_content).find('#name').val('New test value').parent();
    alert(test.find('#name').val());
    alert(test.html());
    return false;
});
```

also available at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tndn7/). The first `alert` displays `"New test value"`, yet the second `alert` doesn't reveal any hint of how this new value is stored - basically it returns the same value as the original variable `form_content`.

I've had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2352080/182048), but can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Could anyone please help me connect the dots, and possibly give me a hint of how I can change the html stored in `form_content`? (There seems to be plenty of examples of how to do it in plain static html, but that's unfortunately not an option for me.) Thanks!

Comment: it is because the updated value is not copied to the value attribute.. it is maintained in the value property of the input element.. when you say html() it gets the inner html along with its attributes not the properties

Comment: The Attribute of an input does not change when you change the value property with .val() . The inputs value will change, but not the attr. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tndn7/1/

Comment: The `val` methods sets the value property, if you want to change the `value` attribute of your input tag, try `attr('val', 'new test value')`. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/tndn7/3/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346471/why-doesnt-the-value-attribute-of-the-input-change

Comment: Thanks all for those helpful comments! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    var form_content = "<form><input id=\"name\" value=\"Test value\"/></form>";
    var test = $('<div />').html(form_content).find('#name').attr('value', 'New test value').parent();
    alert(test.find('#name').attr('value'));
    alert(test.html());
    return false;
});
```

Update your query, its working fine...

Comment: Thanks @Sam1604 for the most complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use .val('new test value'), instead use .attr('value', 'new test value')

Answer (score 0):

Just put the type for you input element
try

```
      <input type="hidden" id="name" value="Test value">
```